# Find the Conditional Probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

This is a classic question, and I understand the answer from one approach, but I'm trying to understand it the underlying conditional probabilities.

> We have two bags: Bag A contains 5 keys, Bag B contains 7 keys.
> One of the 12 key's fits a lock.
> If we select a bag and key at random what is the probability we find the correct key $P(F)$.

**Answer:**
We partition the event space into 4 possibilities, and sum the appropriate events multiplied by the probability of finding the key given that event.

1. $A_1$ Key in Bag A, and we Pick A: $P(A_1) = 5/12 • 1/2 = 5/24$
2. $A_2$ Key in Bag B, and we Pick A: $P(A_2) = 7/12 • 1/2 = 7/24$
3. $B_1$ Key in Bag B, and we Pick B: $P(B_1) = 7/12 • 1/2 = 7/24$
4. $B_2$ Key in Bag A, and we Pick B: $P(B_2) = 5/12 • 1/2 = 5/24$

$P(F) = 1/5P(A_1) + 1/7P(B_1) = 1/12$

**Questions:**
I'm struggling to work out the conditional probability's $P(F|A_1)$ & $P(F|A)$:
And if i have worked them out correctly, why they make sense:

1. $P(F|A_1)$ = $\frac{P(F \cap A_1)}{P(A_1)}$ = $\frac{(1/5)(5/24)}{5/24}$ = $1/5$ =  $\frac{P(A_1|F)P(F)}{P(A_1)}$ = $\frac{P(A_1|F)1/12}{5/24}$

- Therefore: $P(A_1|F) = 1/2$
- I think $1/5$ makes intuitive sense, but i'm not happy with my calculations:
- I've basically written: $P(F|A_1) = \frac{P(F|A_1)P(A_1)}{P(A_1)}$ This feels wrong? A tautology?
- $P(A_1|F) = 1/2$ I'm unsure of, and am not finding intuitive.
- I guess $P(A_1|F) = 1/2$ could be saying that if we know we have found the key, then it had to be in either scenario $A_1$ or $B_1$ but given they are weighted differently i'm unclear why $P(A_1|F) = 1/2$

2. $P(F|A) =  \frac{P(F \cap A)}{P(A)}$ = $\frac{(5/24)(1/5)}{1/2}$ = $1/12$ = $\frac{P(A|F)P(F)}{P(A)}$ = $\frac{P(A|F)1/12}{1/2}$

- Therefore: $P(A|F) = 1/2$
- Again, I think $P(F|A) = 1/12$ makes intuitive sense, as just because we have picked bag A, doesn't make it any more likely, that the Key is in  Bag A, and hence doesn't effect the overall probability of finding the key.
- $P(A|F) = 1/2$ like before is bothering me, I suppose the previous logic could apply? We've found the key, which bag did we pick, it has to be one of the two 50/50....But that doesn't feel right?

I'd be very grateful for help deciphering these conditional probabilities and the intuition behind them! Thanks!

**Additional Context:** Picture of original question and answer.

[image]

Comment: I do not understand the problem setup very well.  Do we randomly select a lock, randomly mix the keys, and then put them into their respective bags randomly such that five go into one bag and seven into the other?  If so, then $P(F)=\frac{1}{12}$ by simple observation that we could have reworded the process to selecting the lock at the end rather than the beginning of the random process, and so the question is what the probability is that the lock matched what key we selected.

Comment: Hi @JMoravitz I agree. It's not entirely clear. I have posted a picture of the exact question and answer from the course pack. I think he purpose of the question is to make you realise that just arbitrarily portioning the 12 nails into x bags, shouldn't effect the probability. Which I guess makes sense.  See the picture for clarity!

Comment: If you were able to clarity what those two conditional probabilities I have written down would be, and why. I'd be super grateful!

Comment: The point here is that the increased chance that the special key is in the bigger bag exactly offsets the decreased chance that you'll pick the right key out of the bigger bag.  If bag $A$ has $a$ keys and $B$ has $b$ then winning with bag $A$ has a probability of $\frac a{a+b}\times \frac 12\times \frac 1a=\frac 1{2(a+b)}$ with the same result for $B$.  Does that answder your question?

Comment: For $P(F\mid A_1)$, we can pretend we selected which lock it was at the beginning of the random process before mixing keys in order to let this make sense.  Supposing the correct key for the lock is in bag $A$ and bag $A$ was chosen, then the probability we pick the correct key will simply be $\frac{1}{5}$.  This is identical to the problem of where we only had a single bag and five keys, one of which works. As for $P(F\mid A)$ we can go back to imagining that the lock was randomized after having placed keys and having selected a key.  This will be $\frac{1}{12}$ since all locks equally likely

Comment: Thank you @Lulu for you answer, your quote: "The point here is that the increased chance that the special key is in the bigger bag exactly offsets the decreased chance that you'll pick the right key out of the bigger bag." This was my intuitive understanding but you phrased it in a way which added great clarity, thank you! The algebraic explanation is also very helpful! The only thing Im missing is the correct formula for the Conditional probabilities

Comment: Thank you! @JMoravitz And apologies as well for my delay in responding, these messages slipped through my inbox. That's a very helpful response, would you be able to write down the correct Bayes formulae for me for $P(F|A_1)$?

Comment: If you or Lulu have the time to give one example of the correct Bayes formulae for the conditional probabilities that'd be very kind! Thanks as well for the previous help!